# set child element height to max({own height}, {height of other children within parent})

Tags: css, shiny

The structure of the page below contains

```
dashboardBody(
wellPanel(
  fluidRow(
    box(width = 6,
          DT::dataTableOutput("topLineTable"),
          uiOutput("promoOverlapUI")
    ),
    box(width = 6,
        selectInput("selectGraph2", label=NULL, choices=NULL),
        uiOutput("baselineGraphUI2")
    )
  ),
  #other stuff...
)
```

[image]

I'd like to make it so the shorter element expands to fill the fluidRow. I tried height=100% without success. The element that won't expand is `box()`,  (`col-sm-6` is generated by `box()`)
I'd like to avoid absolute pixel sizing.

Comment: Any reason someone downvoted this 7 month old question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `display:flex;` on the `row` and `col-sm-6` classes,.

You could add:

```
tags$style(HTML("div.row,div.col-sm-6 {display:flex;}"))
```

to your `dashboardbody` for example.